# Index slice within Main func when using setGrade()

Tags: go, struct, slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Student struct {
    Name  string
    Grade []int
    Age   int
}

func (s *Student) setAge(age int) {
    s.Age = age
}
func (s *Student) setGrade(grade []int) {

    s.Grade = grade
}
func (s *Student) setName(name string) {
    s.Name = name
}
func main() {
    s := Student{"Klaus", []int{90, 75, 100}, 19}
    fmt.Println(s)
    s.setAge(20)
    fmt.Println(s)
    s.setGrade([]int{80})
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

The problem is when I'm doing `setGrade` in the main function it's behaving like new(grade) and giving me this

```
{Klaus [90 75 100] 19}
{Klaus [90 75 100] 20}
{Klaus [80] 20}
```

Here, the slice `s.setGrade([]int{10})` is giving the output `{Klaus [10] 20}`
I came up with a static and stupid idea by using an index in

```
func (s *Student) setGrade(grade []int) {
    s.Grade[0] = grade
}
```

but I have a problem, I have to give the number static when the grade changes with specific index

Required OUTPUT:-

```
{Klaus [90 75 100] 19}
{Klaus [90 75 100] 20}
{Klaus [80 75 100] 20}
```

Required solution:-
i some how want to give specific index in main func imagine python this way `s.setGrade(grade[0])` i know this wont work in GO but i want to do this way!
or let me know is there any other way of doing!`

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do, please can you clarify the last part. Should the setGrade function change a grade, or add a new grade to the grade slice? If you just want to change the first element in the slice: `s.Grade[0] = grade` is correct.

Comment: If you want to change a specific grade, why you are not passing the index of the grade itself? like `s.setGrate(80, 0)` that means change the 0th grade to 80.

Comment: @meshkati can u provide me correct code that i can make sure you are correct! i didn't get your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in method what you're looking for (merging slices). However, you can use append method like:

```
s.setGrade(append([]int{80}, s.Grade[1:]...))
```

If you had to update two grade ints then you could have done:

```
s.setGrade(append([]int{80,95}, s.Grade[2:]...))
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem:**

Your current setGrade function accepts a slice of integers → `setGrade(grade []int)`

Inside of the function, you are setting the existing slice, `Grade`, to the slice passed into the setGrade function → `s.Grade = grade`

This is replacing `Grade` with an entirely new slice. This is not what you want to do.

**The Solution**

If you want  to change a **specific** value in the slice, your function should accept 2 parameters:

1. The **index** of the slice that you want to update
2. The **NEW value** that you want to set at that index

Your function should use the index to identify the value that should be changed and then set it to the passed in value. Like this:

```
    func (s *Student) setGrade(index int, newValue int)  {
        s.Grade[index] = newValue
    }
```